# How to convert hours, minutes and seconds to seconds

Tags: time

I should convert hours, minutes and seconds to seconds,but the problem is that the program can take as an input 3 format types. The first is in the format 54 (which means there are only 54 sec) , sometimes in the format 45:56 (which means 45 minutes and 56 seconds) and sometimes in the format (12:35:12) which means 12 hour 35 minutes and 12 seconds. For example if i want to input those numbers and convert them to seconds i don't know when should i use cin for character ':' 
I tried this one but i couldn't input the space character:

```
char a;
int nr,arr[1000],cnt=0,sum=0;
while (a==':')
{
    cin>>nr>>a;
    cnt++;
    arr[cnt]=nr;
}
if (cnt==1) sum=arr[1];
if (cnt==2) sum=60*arr[1]+arr[2];
if (cnt==3) sum=3600*arr[1]+60*arr[2]+arr[3];
```

Comment: What language is this, and how is it related to time zones or timers?  Please use the appropriate tags. Thanks.

Comment: Can you understand what i tried to say now, because i made some changes

Comment: Please tag the the question with the language that it applies to, so that people who understand the language can find your question.  It looks like C++ to me, but you never know.

Comment: I am sorry but i misunderstood what you said before... Yes it is c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char time[9];
    int sum;

    cin>>time;

    char *t1=strtok(time,":");
    char *t2=strtok(NULL,":");
    if (t2==NULL)
        sum=atoi(t1);
    else {
        char *t3=strtok(NULL,":");
        if (t3==NULL)
            sum=atoi(t1)*60+atoi(t2);
        else
            sum=atoi(t1)*3600+atoi(t2)*60+atoi(t3);
    }

    cout<<sum<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about when the input is 1000000000:1000000000:1000000000 and i just want to display in the format days:hours:minutes:seconds (not by using %60 since we do not know whether it has only seconds or minutes and seconds or hours, minutes and seconds)

Comment: Couldn't understand what you're saying. What do you mean by `1000000000:1000000000:1000000000`? You can try to ask this in a separate question.